# ZED Air CX3 Webcam Not Working in Ubuntu 22.04 (Windows 10 Works)

Tags: webcam

I have a problem with my Yibin Wei Heng Digital ZED Air CX3 laptop. The built-in webcam is not functioning correctly when I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.03.

The webcam works perfectly when I use Windows 10 as my primary operating system,  however when I switch to Ubuntu 22.04 webcam software like Cheese displays `No Device Found`. I've tried reinstalling Cheese and using alternative webcam applications, but none of them have been able to detect the webcam. The fact that the webcam works in Windows 10 suggests that the issue is likely related to driver compatibility or configuration within Ubuntu.

I've also taken the following troubleshooting steps:

- Checked permissions: I verified that my user account has the necessary permissions to access video devices.
- I confirmed that the uvcvideo kernel module is loaded.
- I tried using the Guvcview application, but it also couldn't access the webcam.
- I made sure that I have the latest kernel and drivers installed.

Additional information:

- Laptop model: Yibin Wei Heng Digital Co., Ltd. ZED Air CX3
- Operating system: Ubuntu 22.04.03
- Kernel version: 6.5.0-14-generic
- Original purchase information: LifeDigital Zed Intel Core i3 5th Gen 5005U, purchased from Flipkart